# Ascending Numbers from array for each individual element

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, count

I didn´t get an answer yesterday on this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206351/jquery-slider-with-newest-content-first-gets-reversed-thumbnails-clicking-on-fi

So I tried for a simpler solution. I want to change this code:

```
$news_countpp = 6;
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".($news_page * $news_countpp).", $news_countpp");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<div><a href='#".$row['id']."' class='cross-link'><img src='/assets/images/news/news_".$row['id']."_slider_thumb.jpg' alt='".$row['news_img_alt']."'  class='nav-thumb' alt='temp-thumb' style='width:60px; height:40px;'></a></div>";
}
```

The Part `<a href='#".$row['id']."` would echo descending numbers from #6 - #1. (newest news hast highest ID)
I want the numbers to be ascending instead (not according to the id) than it works.

I tried the following array instead of ".row['id'].":

```
$thumblink = array ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6');
for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
echo $thumblink[$i];
}
```

But this gives each of my 6 thumbnails the href "123456" instead of ascending numbers from 1 - 6 for the individual thumbnails. Do you know what I do wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery slider with newest content first gets reversed thumbnails (clicking on first thumb will trigger last)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206351/jquery-slider-with-newest-content-first-gets-reversed-thumbnails-clicking-on-fi)

Comment: If your question isn't getting answers because it needs to be rewritten, then you are encouraged to rewrite the existing question.  It's generally considered bad form to keep posting additional questions, unless your question got an answer that led to a followup question.

Comment: @GordonM This isn't a re-post of that question, so I'm not sure it makes sense to mark it as a duplicate. Yes, they *could* have completely changed the other question because it has no answers, but asking a new question is also valid since it's a different one.

Comment: do you want to achieve something like this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52b1d/5

Comment: @GordonM: I already rephrased the last question once and still got no answer. As Anthony Grist already said, I tried a completely different solution here and got now the answer that I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$news_countpp = 6;
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".($news_page * $news_countpp).", $news_countpp");
$i = 1
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<div><a href='#".$i."' class='cross-link'><img src='/assets/images/news/news_".$row['id']."_slider_thumb.jpg' alt='".$row['news_img_alt']."'  class='nav-thumb' alt='temp-thumb' style='width:60px; height:40px;'></a></div>";
$i++;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you're iterating over the entire array for every iteration of the `while` loop. Instead, initialise the array and a counter variable to `0` prior to the `while` loop, and only access one element per iteration (incrementing the counter by one as you do so).

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $i++;
  echo 
    "<div>",
      "<a href='#".$row['id']."' class='cross-link'>",
        "<img src='/assets/images/news/news_", $row[$i], "_slider_thumb.jpg'
          alt='".$row['news_img_alt']."'  
          class='nav-thumb' alt='temp-thumb' 
          style='width:60px; height:40px;'>",
      "</a>",
    "</div>";
}
```

Comment: If you want 6 to 0 make the first line `$i = 6;` and the third `$i--;`